# read input type in function using objective C

Tags: objective-c

Please help me I am stuck on this point...

I know only PHP and basic idea of C.

I create a code which calling a function and gives  result....

In below i have main function which calling add metod and read input from other functions.......

Question Is  how we pass args ?
                   why its not give o/p ?
                   When i directyly assigne value to ip1 and ip2 its give result ?
                   So how we read input using command line....

```
#import<Foundation/Foundation.h>

int add(int input1,int input2)
{
    int result = input1 + input2;
    return result;
}

char* GetString(char* a)
{
    int i = 0;  
        while(a[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(a[i] == '_')
            a[i] = ' ';
                else if(a[i] == '{')
            a[i] = ' ';
                else if(a[i] == '}')
            a[i] = ' ';
        i++;
    }
    return a;
}

int GetInt(char *input)
{
    int num = [input intValue];
    return num;
}


int main(int argc, char *a[0])
{

    int output = 0;
    int ip1;
    int ip2;

   NSLog(@"value of c : %d \n", a[0]);

    ip1 = GetInt(a[1]); // 4
    ip2 = GetInt(a[2]);  // 5



    output = add(ip1,ip2);

    NSLog(@"output %d", output);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int GetInt(char *input)
{
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:input];
    int num = [string intValue];
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `intValue` is a method on the `NSString` class and you are passing a C `char` array.  Therefore change the `GetInt()` function to the following (a pointless function anyway given the `intValue` method is immediately available):

```
int GetInt(NSString *input)
{
    int num = [input intValue];
    return num;
}
```

and convert the command line arguments to `NSString` instances using `@(string)`:

```
if (argc >= 3) {
    ip1 = GetInt(@(a[1])); // 4
    ip2 = GetInt(@(a[2]));  // 5
}
```

(You shouldn't be dereferencing `a[1]` or `a[2]` unless `argc >= 3`, as the program will crash).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to study syntax creation for `Objective-c`.
Here are some links that might help you:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_basic_syntax.htm
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Objective-C_Programming/syntax
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html